# Date Picker with the option to select All?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, datepicker, jquery-plugins

I'm wondering if there is a datepicker plug-in which has the option to be able to select All Dates. Appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: usually you can select a *range*, which can be used to select all. (what is *all* date? it doesn't really make sense to me)

Comment: @appleapple _all_ date can be selecting, let's say, 2-3 years of dates

Comment: range select can do it just right, but I think you simply do not use a date picker if you want all dates are selected. (by a separated checkbox or something)